# how a click on url.action open view on the same view in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have view name Test having a side-nav bar

```
 <div id='sidebar-nav'>
  ...

  <li style="color:black"><a href=@Url.Action("Desc", 
  "Home",new{id=@obj})>@obj</li>
  ...

</div>

<div id="div2"></div>
```

on the click of any of the navbar content link I want the Desc view to load in div 2 
How can I do it?
I googled It but could not understand much as New to asp.net

Comment: Is the `div2` hidden at first time? You can use JS function e.g. `$('a[id=^@obj]').click(function () { $('#div2').show(); }` or use jQuery dialog to load partial views inside popup (depending on what you want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for load `div2`.

**Example:**

```
 <div id='sidebar-nav'>
  ...

  <li style="color:black"><a href='@Url.Action("Desc", 
  "Home",new{id=@obj})'>@obj</li>
  ...

</div>

<div id="div2"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("li>a").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#div2").load($(this).attr("href"));
        });
    });
</script>
```